# Unable to install kubelet from ansible

Tags: ansible, repository, yum, errno

I'm trying to install kubelet with **Ansible**, but I'm struggling to do it.

This is my **playbook**:

```
---
  - hosts: all
    become: yes
    tasks:
      - name: install docker
        yum:
          name: docker
          state: present
          update_cache: true

      - name: add repo
        yum_repository:
          name: kuberepo
          description: kubernetes-repo
          baseurl: "https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64"
          enabled: yes
          gpgcheck: yes
          repo_gpgcheck: yes
          gpgkey:
            - "https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg"
            - "https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg"

      - name: setenforce
        shell: setenforce 0

      - name: install kubelet
        yum:
          name: kubelet
          state: present
          update_cache: true
```

This is the **error** when i run the playbook (ansible-playbook -i hosts kube-dependencies.yml)
[image: ansible error]

The "ok" from [master] node is because I manually executed "sudo yum install kubelet" on that machine, and it worked.

**Conclusions:**
So basically, manually executing the yum install command it works, but I can't make it work with ansible.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about adding the commands to a script file and run provision ?

Comment: That would probably work, but I really want to know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: It could be that some of the operations are taking more time. As the log indicates the google part may take some time. To verify that, add is manually and run the remaining ones with Ansible.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the time, it takes few seconds to give the error. But if no other option comes up, I'll do what you say. Basically, remove the "add repo" from the ansible playbook and calls it from a script. But I'll never know the true problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I fix it adding version of kubelet
apt:

```
   name: kubelet=1.20.0-00
   state: present
   update_cache: true
```

That worked for me

same issue with kubeletadm

```
- name: install kubeadm
 apt:
   name: kubeadm=1.14.0-00
   state: present
```

**Error**
[image: error]

solution

```
- name: install kubeadm
 apt:
   name: kubeadm=1.20.0-00
   state: present
```

**Fix the problem**
[image: fix the problem]

I hope I've helped

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to upgrade the version to install.
in every new version k8s changed many configs so some components become npt compatible (kubelet vs kubernetes-cni (= 0.7.5) are not compatible.

version up, if not works then find another solution.

hope that this clarification help.